# upload_to dynamically generated url to callable

Tags: python, django, models

I've seen a lot of post about this problem without really understanding how to solve it.

I have this model:

```
class Project(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='no name')
    logo = models.ImageField()
```

I'd like to have my image saved to media root following this template:

```
<name>/logo/<filename>
```

At first glance, I would like to do:

`logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="{}/logo/".format(name))`

But it raises this error: `AttributeError: 'TextField' object has no attribute 'model'`

Using a callable would be fine, partially though:

```
def upload_to_project(self, filename):
    url = ("%s/%s") % (self.name, filename)
    return url
```

and using:

```
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_project)
```

at least I have: `<name>/<filename>`

But how to pass the  argument in this case? I'd like to reuse my function to upload in other subfolders, not only `logo` as:

```
<name>/logo/<filename>
<name>/history/<filename>
<name>/whatever/<filename>
```

Any idea on what I could do?

Comment: Where would this argument be provided? I don't think this is possible. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: I though something like providing it during the call to upload_to. But indeed, it may not be possible. Or I should change my strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like *(re-reading your post it's not 100% clear)* what you want is a [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Good news, it's part of Python's stdlib:

```
import os
from functools import partial

def generic_upload_to(instance, filename, folder):
    return os.path.join(instance.name, folder, filename)


class Project(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='no name')
    logo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=partial(generic_upload_to, folder="logo")
        )
```

Note that this implementation assumes `instance` has a `name` attribute... if the instance attribute you want to use as first part has to be configurable too you can rewrite your `upload_to` as:

```
def generic_upload_to(instance, filename, folder, attrname):
    return os.path.join(getattr(instance, attrname), folder, filename)
```

then use it as

```
class Project(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='no name')
    logo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=partial(generic_upload_to, attrname="name", folder="logo")
        )
```

And if you have more than one `FileField` or `ImageField` in your model and don't want to repeat the `attrname` part:

```
class Something(TimeStampedModel):
    my_upload_to = partial(generic_upload_to, attrname="label")

    label = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='no label')
    logo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=partial(my_upload_to, folder="logo")
        )
    attachment = models.FileField(
        upload_to=partial(my_upload_to, folder="attachment")
        )
```

Comment: This is a great solution!